# why is regcomp slower in perl 5.16.2 than perl 5.8.8?

Tags: regex, perl

Running the following script on these two versions of perl (5.8.8 and 5.16.2) shows that 5.16.2 is slower than 5.8.8 with regex-operations. Why is that so ? And, is there a way i can speed things up ?

```
    use Time::HiRes 'time';

    for my $regex (
            q{^a$|^b$},
            q{^(a|b)$},
            q{(a|b)},
            q{^a$|^b$|^c$|^d$|^e$|^f$},
            q{^(a|b|c|d|e|f)$},
            q{a|b|c|d|e|f},
    ) {
            my $start = time();

            for my $i (1 .. 100_000) {
                    'SOMEBIGSTRINGHERE' =~ m{$regex};
            }

            my $runtime = time() - $start;
            printf("%50s: %f\n", $regex, $runtime);
    }
```

with perl 5.8.8 -

```
                  ^a$|^b$: 0.101017
                  ^(a|b)$: 0.017527
                    (a|b): 0.107669
  ^a$|^b$|^c$|^d$|^e$|^f$: 0.163687
          ^(a|b|c|d|e|f)$: 0.022244
              a|b|c|d|e|f: 0.171675
```

with perl 5.16.2 -

```
                   ^a$|^b$: 0.254984
                   ^(a|b)$: 0.031507
                     (a|b): 0.045713
   ^a$|^b$|^c$|^d$|^e$|^f$: 0.443303
           ^(a|b|c|d|e|f)$: 0.031506
               a|b|c|d|e|f: 0.043478
```

Comment: What kind of a speed difference are we talking about?

Comment: 've updated the question with the time differences between the two perl versions. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you change `q{}` to `qr{}` and `m{$regex}` to `$regex` does it make a difference? (At least in the version(s) that support it.)

Comment: It didnt in 5.16.2, but did in 5.8.8. Check this http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators and http://ideone.com/P1m7Gl. Does perl 5.16.2 not precompile ?

Comment: and http://codepad.org/meht2abX - codepad runs perl v5.8.0 and ideone runs 5.16.2

Comment: What is "it" in "It didnt"?

Comment: changing q{} to qr{} and m{$regex} to $regex improved runtime in v5.8.8, not in v5.16.2

Answer (score 4):

The primary cause of slowdowns in the regex engine are bug fixes. i.e. Doing things correctly is slower than doing them wrong.

Comment: What kind of bugs? Sounds interesting. Any info on that? Unicode/UTF8 related? (In that case would flags like `/a` make a difference?)

Comment: One of you guys may want to sift through the [list of changes](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html) and try to find the relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

I did test your program several times on my machine. Each run got different times, the individual differences being sometimes larger than most of your differences between versions.

I'd call the variation between versions insignificant.
BTW, your comparison shows the following ranking:

slower/slower/**faster**/slower/slower/**faster**

for 5.16.2 vs. 5.8.8

In fact, you are doing 100,000 times almost nothing. Try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes 'time';
my $str = 'SOMEBIGSTRINGHERE_ somebigstringhere ' x 10000;
for my $regex ( qr{^a$|^b$},
                qr{^(a|b)$},
                qr{(a|b)},
                qr{^a$|^b$|^c$|^d$|^e$|^f$},
                qr{^(a|b|c|d|e|f)$},
                qr{a|b|c|d|e|f} ) {
     my $start = time();
     for my $i (1 .. 100) {
        $str =~ /$regex/;
     }

     my $runtime = time() - $start;
     printf("%50s: %f\n", $regex, $runtime);
 }
```

Now you can see whether the regex engine is involved at all (or left immediately).